# Admob problems in intel xdk

Tags: admob, intel-xdk

I hava a app that i want to show the ads not on index.html but say on index1.html

Everything works great on index.html with the admob script below, banner and interstitial shows up, but i dont whant them on index.html, i want them on index1.html. i delete the code from index.html and put it in index1.html no ads is showing up?

Why is that?

Whay i want them to index1 is that its not very user friendly to hav a interstitial to pop up 1sec after appstart.

i was also thinking to call the interstitial on the first button click but i cant get that working either.

iam using the AdMob Plugin Pro (cordova-plugin-admobpro)
in intel xdk

this is the admobpro script that i use in the html file:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script>var admobid = {};
if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
    admobid = { // for Android
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };
} else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    admobid = { // for iOS
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };
} else {
    admobid = { // for Windows Phone
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };
}
if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
} else {
    initApp();
}
function initApp() {
    if (! AdMob ) { alert( 'admob plugin not ready' ); return; }

    AdMob.createBanner( {
        adId: admobid.banner, 
        isTesting: false,
        overlap: false, 
        offsetTopBar: false, 
        position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
        bgColor: 'black'
    } );
    AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
        adId: admobid.interstitial,
        autoShow: true
    });
}</script>
```

Comment: The solution lies probably in the parts not included in the question - the remaining html files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to build a "multi-page" app (multiple HTML files), you need to include `cordova.js` on each HTML page that accesses JavaScript extensions provided by Cordova plugins. In other words, only those HTML pages that include the magic `cordova.js` init script can access Cordova plugin APIs.

In general, multi-page web apps are not advised for building Cordova apps, because of this issue and because your app will experience delays when switching between pages. You will also lose the JavaScript context, which can cause logical problems in your app.

I recommend that you rebuild your app so it is a "single-page" app (aka SPA). See [this Cordova doc article](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/index.html), especially the section titled *SPA is Your Friend!*